# How to use ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated for multiple hits

Tags: selenium

I have a HTML site containing several context menues.
The xpath is: .//*[@id='TopIcon_Edit']/a/span. (This path will hit several elements)
In my test one of the context menues is visible.

I now want to verify that one context menu is visible, using 
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='TopIcon_Edit']/a/span")).
Although I can see that the context menu is visible, the test tells me:
"Element does not meet condition visibility of element located by By.xpath: ..."

I assume that the method visibilityOfElementLocated(...) just evaluates the visibility of the first element it finds by the locator, which is not visible, as Selenium rightly sais.

I would appreciate any hints on how to solve this problem.

With kind regards,
Gerhard Schuster

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you search single element with Selenium and result returns more than one element, the method takes the first element and returns it.
So, you have to specify more precisely the xpath you using, for example: ".//*[@id='TopIcon_Edit']/a[1]/span", or similar, that will point only desired element.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do away with xpath that would help.  FindElement(By.cssSelector("#TopIcon_Edit span")).click() or do a list of web elements we = FindElements (By.cssSelector("#TopIcon_Edit span"));  then filter your list based on style.  Its far easier and provides greater flexibility to use cssSelectors.